# Debian 'bullseye' - mouse pointer disappears on GNOME3 backgrounds

Tags: debian, gnome3, desktop-environment, desktop, gnome-shell

Since some recent upgrades on my Debian system, I experience the mouse pointer disappearing in front of Gnome backgrounds, meaning the top-bar, the desktop and system window. As soon as the pointer is moved in front of a window of any application it appears again.

I did some research on this topic and did not find more then it might have to to with one of the following packages:

```
xserver-xorg-input-mouse 
installed version: 1:1.9.3-1
```

and or:

```
mutter
installed version: 3.30.2-9
```

**Some more system info:**

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
            Kernel: Linux 5.2.0-2-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
       GNOME shell: 3.30.2
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different kernel version. It looks like 5.1 or 5.3 should be OK.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/772#note_600786

As a temporary workaround, when the cursor disappears, perform some action that changes the cursor.  Some people use the screenshot shortcut.  I press the windows key, and move the invisible cursor into/across the search text box.  The cursor will then re-appear.

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/772#note_600745

Be patient waiting for the above links to load. They appear to rely on client-side templating (sigh), and there are too many comments.